# Why does a linux pipe slow my data transfer?

Tags: linux, bash, dd, pipe

I noticed that if I use `dd` to move data from `/dev/zero` to `/dev/null`, I can max out around 6.1GB/s by adjusting the block size.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress bs=512k count=2k
# 2048+0 records in
# 2048+0 records out
# 1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.1768 s, 6.1 GB/s
```

However, if I `dd` the zeros device to the null device via a pipe, I max out around 1.4GB/s which is around a factor of 4.4 performance hit.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=64k count=16k status=none | dd of=/dev/null status=progress bs=64k
# 16384+0 records in
# 16384+0 records out
# 1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.794066 s, 1.4 GB/s
```

I realize that the `dd` blocksize is different in the two examples; using `bs=512` with the pipe yielded a transfer rate of 176MB/s.

Based on what I could find on the internet, I think the degradation in speed has something to do with the pipe's buffering behavior but I do not understand why. Thanks in advance for any explanations.

Comment: [This answer on our sister site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607745/108618).

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! I can't believe I did not see this answer before.